# Language mismatch in Apple menu bar

Tags: macos, keyboard, language, internationalization

The default language on my iMac is Italian, however, after restoring from a time machine backup, the language of the shutdown and reboot options from the menu bar have mixed language.
[image]

The "countdown" is in Italian but the other text is not, as you can see. Also, the text of the password prompt of the lock screen is in English too, "Enter password". I tried switching the language to English and back to Italian but it didn't work. I'm running OS X 10.11.6.

Answer (score -1):

Solved by running

```
sudo languagesetup
```

Solution from the ‘If there’s more than one user account on your Mac’ part from the Apple KB article [Change the language used at the login screen on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202036).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.